# Can someone help me see why this code is not working?

Tags: python, file

```
    A_file = open("ReadME.txt","r")

    print(A_file.read())
```

The output I am getting is 2 new lines and that is it... The text i am 
        trying to get is "Line 1, Line 2, Line 3".

Comment: Did you try `A_file.readlines()`?

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, the output to that is '[ ]'. I am very confused thank you for trying to help

Comment: So, your file is empty?

Comment: No, I has stuff in it

Comment: @Antithesis I don't get an error but my code is just not working yet I did all the right things.

Comment: Is there any chance you have the file open in a text editor, but you have not saved the changes to the file?

Comment: also, is the file that has content in the same directory as the python script!?

Comment: +Keerthana Prabhakaran yes

Comment: And you're certain that the current working directory is the one containing the script and "ReadME.txt"? You can check that by putting `import os; print(os.getcwd())` in the script.

Answer (score -1):

What is the error message?

Try doing this first.

```
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('helloworld')
```

Then run the next bit exactly as I wrote it. This will write a file that had text.

Also, do this instead. It should give you all the lines in your file.

```
with open('readme.txt', 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()

print(content)
```

Comment: True, I did this from my phone and half asleep. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Anithesis the same output came back as when I did .read().... My .txt has words in it though

Comment: Check out my edits. You can run the new thing to make sure you have a file with text.

Comment: My guess is you have accidentally created a second file with the same name in your working directory that's empty, and the one you intend to read is in another directory.

Comment: Can someone explain why my answer was downvotes? This works, you can test it yourself